# Is there something similar to RemoteApp for MacOS

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I'm wondering if MacOS has something similar to the Windows RemoteApp that would allow publishing of an app that runs on the MacOS.  I use Windows as my main environment and wish to use iMessage on Windows.  Is there anything that will allow me to just have a published app instead having to do a full Remote (VNC) session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that the X11 system for macOS supports something similar to RemoteApp - i.e. allows you to run an app on a distant server and it shows up on your desktop like any other app in its own window - without a full desktop environment like VNC.
However you cannot run the Messages app this way.

The only solution I can think of that comes near to what you want is to run macOS in a virtual machine on your Windows computer, and then use features in the virtualisation software to show each guest application in its own host window. In VMWare this is known as "Unity mode", however VMware currently only supports that mode for Windows guests. In the theoretical case that a later VMware version supports this, remember to check that your for macOS at that time allows you to run the operating system on Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure we should be recommending unlicensed VMs on Windows, really.

Comment: I'm not recommending, I'm actually stating that it isn't possible currently. However, I have just added to the answer that if this should become possible in the future, jpsil will ofcourse like any other have to obey licensing agreements for the software.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  What is the limitation of X11 forwarding that won't allow running the Messages app, assuming licensing isn't an issue?

Comment: It only works with X apps, which Messages.app isn’t.